# It is displaying only the first element of list.Can anyone tell me what the error is?

Tags: python, data-science

```
def read_csv(file_name):
    f=open(file_name).read()
    lis=f.split("\n")
    string_list=lis[1:len(lis)-1]
    final_list=[]
    for a in string_list:
        string_fields=a.split(",")
        int_field=[];    
        for value in string_fields:
            int_field.append(int(value))
        final_list.append(int_field)
        return(final_list)
cdc_list=read_csv("US_births_1994-2003_CDC_NCHS.csv")
print(cdc_list[0:10])
```

This shows only the first element of cdc list.I am unable to find the error

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data?

Comment: I have experience similar issues in the past, because you only have one element in your list. It could be your code only loads the first element of the CSV, or the CSV only has one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of your indentation. When you read your code you'll see, that you `return` from your function after the first `value` in `string_list`

Move your return 4 spaces to the left and it should work:

```
def read_csv(file_name):
    f=open(file_name).read()
    lis=f.split("\n")
    string_list=lis[1:len(lis)-1]
    final_list=[]
    for a in string_list:
        string_fields=a.split(",")
        int_field=[];    
        for value in string_fields:
            int_field.append(int(value))
        final_list.append(int_field)
    return(final_list)
cdc_list=read_csv("US_births_1994-2003_CDC_NCHS.csv")
print(cdc_list[0:10])
```

a shorter version:

```
def read_csv(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        #read lines
        lines = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
        #remove header
        lines = lines[1:]
        # split lines and cast to integer
        lines = [[int(val) for val in line.split(',')] for line in lines]
    return(lines)
```